# AZTabBarController doesn't stick to bottom

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement AZTabBarController within my project but I am struggling to fix the bar to the bottom of the screen. My assumption is that the bar can be fixed to the bottom using some method or that I have some element that is pushing the bar some 50pts higher. Perhaps there is a margin of some sort that keeps the bar from staying at the bottom. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Here is my AZTabBar code. I've borrowed it from the example within the repo.

```
class CustomTabBarController:  UITabBarController {

var tabController: AZTabBarController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var icons = [UIImage]()
    icons.append(UIImage.init(named: "ic_home")!)
    icons.append(UIImage.init(named: "ic_new")!)
    icons.append(UIImage.init(named: "ic_settings")!)

    //The icons that will be displayed for each tab once they are selected.
    var selectedIcons = [UIImage]()
    selectedIcons.append(UIImage.init(named: "ic_home")!)
    selectedIcons.append(UIImage.init(named: "ic_new")!)
    selectedIcons.append(UIImage.init(named: "ic_settings")!)


    tabController = AZTabBarController.insert(into: self, withTabIcons: icons, andSelectedIcons: selectedIcons)

    tabController.delegate = self

    tabController.setViewController(QueryViewController.instance(), atIndex: 0)

    tabController.setViewController(SettingsViewController.instance(), atIndex: 2)

    //customize


    let color = UIColor(red: 14.0/255, green: 122.0/255, blue: 254.0/255, alpha: 1.0)

    tabController.selectedColor = color

    tabController.highlightColor = color

    tabController.highlightedBackgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1803921569, green: 0.8, blue: 0.4431372549, alpha: 1)

    tabController.defaultColor = .lightGray

    //tabController.highlightButton(atIndex: 2)

    tabController.buttonsBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: (247.0/255), green: (247.0/255), blue: (247.0/255), alpha: 1.0)//#colorLiteral(red: 0.2039215686, green: 0.2862745098, blue: 0.368627451, alpha: 1)

    tabController.selectionIndicatorHeight = 0

    tabController.selectionIndicatorColor = color

    tabController.tabBarHeight = 60

    tabController.setAction(atIndex: 0) {
        //Your statments
        print("Home!")
    }

    tabController.setAction(atIndex: 1) {
        //Your statments
        print("NEW Situation!")
    }

    tabController.setAction(atIndex: 2) {
        //Your statments
        print("Settings")
    }

    tabController.animateTabChange = false
    tabController.onlyShowTextForSelectedButtons = false
    tabController.setTitle("Home", atIndex: 0)
    tabController.setTitle("New", atIndex: 1)
    tabController.setTitle("Settings", atIndex: 2)
    //tabController.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 12)

}

override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController?{
    return tabController
}

func getNavigationController(root: UIViewController)->UINavigationController{
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: root)
    navigationController.title = title
    navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1568627506, blue: 0.07450980693, alpha: 1)
    return navigationController
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub classing

```
class CustomTabBarController:  UITabBarController {
```

is the reason you should use `AZTabBarController` directly , what you see as margin in bottom is the parent class's  tabBar which is empty because you don't set any `viewControllers` for it

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! Actually I had to set `UIViewController` instead, since I am using a UIViewController to manage the CustomController. Thanks anyways! This was fantastic!